# UIActionSheet dismisses on 2nd click of the button

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

I have an actionSheet with EDIT and DELETE buttons, both being other buttons  This is the Code i have written for it

```
-(void)method1
{

    action = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil     destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Edit", @"Delete", nil];
     action.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [action showInView:self.view];
    [action release]; 

}
```

I have used the deleate method to assign actions to method..

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)action didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // do something
    }
    if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

now the problem is that the actionsheet does not dismiss at one click of either of the buttons.. Please help me with some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in iOS4.0.  I had this issue in my simulator.  I changed the version to 4.3 and 5.0 and it seemed ok.

**Edit:**

Seems that my issue was more specifically to do with the actionsheet being launched twice by a delegate method "-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField"

Not sure why this is called twice in this case but not others (again I assume a iOS 4.0 bug that's been fixed in later releases).  My workaround is to keep track if it's been called already and not call it a second time.

**Edit 2**

I would suggest doing something like:

```
-(void)method1
{
    if(hasLaunchedActionSheet)
    {
        return;
    }

    hasLaunchedActionSheet = YES;
    ...
```

and:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)action didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    hasLaunchedActionSheet = NO;
    ...
```

For me, the issue's not so much in Xcode as it is in the iOS SDK itself calling my event twice.  I'm not sure how you're calling method1 so it might be a different issue with a different event.

Comment: I'd suggest working around the method firing twice.  See edit 2 above.

Comment: i have used something similar :) :) i saw that the actionsheet is having value nil before its called and some value after its called. so i used if(action == nil){ // do something }.. now it works.. but i thought this would not be a proper approach. but thanks for the help :) :)

Comment: An even simpler approach than mine.  I like it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong delegate methods, for button interaction, you should use:

`-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`

instead of:

`-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)action didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`

Comment: did you copy/pasted and replaced the delegate method I'vew written above? what exactly happens now? it has to work! you can also try change parameter name in this method from action to sth else (it's overlaping property)

Comment: @MichałZygar... i have replaced the delegate methods as u said.. it still dismisses at the second click of the edit or delete button...

Comment: how to dismiss it at one click of a button i dunno

Comment: its actually getting created twice.. i dunno y

Comment: well, check your IBActions then. I cannot help you without the code. Good luck